# What is the interaction between docker run "--publish" and "--publish-all"?

Tags: docker

I couldn't find this documented.  Suppose I wanted to publish one port to a known place, but sometime publish all the other "exposed" ports for debugging or testing.

A simple Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
CMD /bin/sleep 600
```

--publish/-p allows me to bind a specific host port to a container port.  --publish-all/-P binds all container ports to random ports, which can be found using, for example `docker ps`.

```
$ docker build -t foo .
<build prints>
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -P -p 9000:9000 foo
<some id prints>
$ docker ps --format '{{.Command}} {{.Ports}}'
"/bin/sh -c '/bin/sl…" 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp
```

But suppose I have a Dockerfile like this, and publish one port to a known port but the rest to randomly assigned ports.

```
FROM alpine
EXPOSE 8000
# Various management ports or something
EXPOSE 8005
EXPOSE 8443
EXPOSE 8009
CMD /bin/sleep 600
```

What is the defined behavior for

```
$ docker run -d -P -p 8000:8000 foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing exactly this the behavior seems to be "as expected".  The explicit port bindings take precedence over the `--publish-all`, independent of where the flags occur.  In the example above, the results are

```
$ docker ps --format '{{.Command}} {{.Ports}}'
"/bin/sh -c '/bin/sl…" 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32792->8005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32791->8009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32790->8443/tcp
```

The explicit requested port binding occurs, and the other ports are bound to os-assigned unused ports.

It also clarified something to me I did not understand.  I've always mostly ignored "EXPOSE" since the documentation basically said that it doesn't actually do anything but serve as documentation, and to actually "expose" a port you should publish it explicitly.  But `--publish-all` does use the exposed ports.  I had been naively thinking that by doing `--publish-all` it would publish ALL the ports that the process I had started was listening on, but those ports are opened after the container is already initialized.

Comment: It seems that EXPOSE sometimes must be listed after the ENTRYPOINT/CMD in the Dockerfile. At least that is what got this to work for me with a Flask python-app.